# Python Elasticsearch : Index mapping inconsistencies between ‘es.index’ and ‘es.indices.create’

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to implement a custom index mapping (my_mapping) in Python, BUT, I do not get the expected index mapping after the python file is run!

```py
my_mapping = """
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "site": {
                "type": "completion",
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "geo_shape"
            }
        }
    }
}"""
result = es.index(index='my_index', document=my_mapping)
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "geometry": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        },
        "site": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual output:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "mappings": {
          "properties": {
            "properties": {
              "properties": {
                "geometry": { ...........
```

BUT! NOTE that when I instead use the following python to create the index, I DO get the expected outcome.

```py
result = es.index(index='my_index', document=my_mapping)
```

Can someone please explain to me the inconsistency, and HOW to generate the expected outcome USING es.index

Comment: show the python code/data that you are trying to put in the index

Comment: @cerofrais see first code block

Answer (score 1):

Answers from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/python-elasticsearch-index-mapping-inconsistencies-between-es-index-and-es-indices-create/288584

“The es.index is meant to index documents. Not to call the create index API.”

On the other hand, Es.indices.create Creates an index with optional settings and mappings.